# How to enable mouse dragging within a drag and drop enabled div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a div with several elements inside (as expected), and I want to be able to drag and drop this div (`draggable=true`); however, one element is a bar graph that allows a user to drag the mouse across it to select a certain range of data (sort of like how Stack Overflow allows you to view your reputation within certain date ranges--you can find it on your profile under your reputation tab). As you might imagine, I am unable to drag across this graph when its parent div has `draggable` set to `true`, since it just drags the div instead of updating the graph.

I've thought of a number of hacks to get around this, but they all seem rather messy. So I'm wondering what options I have that aren't so hackish. Ideally, I'd be able to drag the entire div by only being able to drag on part of the div.

Comment: This question is slightly difficult to understand exactly what is being asked, try to clarify a little exactly what you are after

Comment: If you navigate here: http://stackoverflow.com/users/6244/toby-allen?tab=reputation you can see the type of graph I'm talking about. If this type of graph is inside a draggable div, you cannot interact with the graph properly, because you will drag the div instead of interacting with the graph. Hopefully that helps?

Answer (score 0):

Setting a "div" to draggable will cause it to be dragged whenever you drag any elements contained within that div. One good way around this is to position the graph inside the div's space using absolute positioning rather than putting it inside the div tags.

Comment: Interesting thought, but I want the graph to move with its parent div, so it would still need to be an element inside the div.